# Differences between name and id attributes in <form> tag

Tags: html

```
<html>
<form action= "/select" method= "POST" accept-charset="utf-8">

<input type= "text" id= "input" name = "input"><BR>
<input type= "submit" id = "submitButton"><BR>

</form>
</html>
```

When I click the submit button on this page, with just the id attribute, it sends nothing over the post request. However, when i put the name attribute, it sends the data. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: name is what is used to submit data with the form submission. Id is used as an identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` attribute is used when sending data in a form.
The `id` attribute is to address a HTML element. So you can use the `id` attribute to style (e.g. with css) or manipulate (e.g. with js) the element.

There is much more to it, but i think you have an idea of the difference now.

Answer (score 1):

On the `<form>` itself: The `id` is for client side operations (such selecting it with CSS or JavaScript or linking to it) while the `name` is for when you are writing in obsolete versions of HTML.

On form controls (like `<input>`): The `id` is for client side operations (like associating it with a `<label>` element, selecting it with JS or CSS, or linking to it) while the `name` will be associated with the value when the form is submitted to the server.